# c++ dice roll analyser (2D arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays, random, 2d, cout

I am doing some c++ practice and trying to write a program to count the amount of times a dice combination is rolled after 10000 attempts. I have used a 2D array to store every possible dice combination, and I perform 10000 `rand()%6+1` and increments the value in the memory allocation it randoms.

This is my attempt.

```
cout << "\nDice roll analyser" << endl;

const int first = 6;
const int second = 6;
int nRolls[first][second];
int count = 0;

while (count < 10000){
    nRolls[rand()%6+1][rand()%6+1]+=1;
    count++;
}

for (int i=0;i<first;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<second;j++){
        cout << nRolls[i][j] << " ";
    }
}
```

This is the output that I get;

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 269 303 265 270 264 228 289 272 294 290 269 262 294 303 277 265 294 288 266 313 274 301 245 317 276 292 284 264 260

What I am trying to achieve is the amount of times each combination is rolled e.g. how many times 1, 6 is rolled etc.

Comment: This is all very nice, but what's the problem/question?

Comment: might be a good idea to initialise the array counts to zero before you start??

Comment: fixed the question to reflect the result i am looking for.

Comment: @pjmil116 Check out the above comment. That might fix your issue.

Comment: After you initialize and fix which indices you are accessing, I would format the output so you can see what is happening.
Also, given your array size `nRolls[6][6]` and `rand()%6+1`, are you getting any seg faults or array out of bounds exceptions?

Comment: No I wasn't, it just wasn't incrementing any values in the first indexes due to the +1. Its fixed now and I've posted the working code below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never update your `count`.

For something where you want to run a code segment n times, where right now n = 10000, this is the general way you wanna do it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
{
    //loop code.
}
```

additionally, `myVariable+=1` can always be simplified to either `++myVariable` or `myVariable++` (if you aren't use the value of myVariable right when you are assigning it, it is better to use the first one. More info on pre/post increment can be found here: http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_015.htm

so instead of `nRolls[rand()%6+1][rand()%6+1]+=1;`
you can instead do

```
++(nRolls[rand()%6+1][rand()%6+1]);
```

Additionally, arrays are zero-indexed, meaning when you do `rand()%6+1` you are restricting the values from `1` to `6` and leaving out the `0` position of an array, which is the first one, so consider instead just using

```
++(nRolls[rand()%6][rand()%6]);
```

then, to find out how often you roll a (i,j), where i and j are between 1 and 6,

```
cout << "(" << i << "," << j << "):" << nRolls[i-1][j-1] << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

You will have a problem here because you are adding +1 to rand()%6 you will never increment the count of any of elements with index zero. The minimum element index you allow to be incremented starts at 1.

Comment: Exactly, arrays go from 0 to n-1.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks for the help. This is the updated code that displays correctly!

```
cout << "\nDice roll analyzer" << endl;

srand(time(0));

const int first = 6;
const int second = 6;
int nRolls[first][second];
int count = 0;

while (count < 10000){
    nRolls[rand()%6][rand()%6]++;
    count++;
}

for (int i=0;i<first;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<second;j++){
        cout << "(" << i+1 << "," << j+1 << ")" << nRolls[i][j] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really, really, really, really use for loops to do n executions for the same line of code.

Comment: yes. when you do `int count = 0; while (count < 10000) { count++; }` that's literally what `for(int count = 0; count < 10000; count++)` is resolved to by the compiler.